# h2o script fails to run via cron

Tags: r, cron, h2o, automl

I am having difficulties when running R script with `h2o` library via `cron` in linux.

The script runs perfectly fine in interactive mode, but when scheduled in `cron` the script fails.

Part of the code causing the error:

```
automl_h2o_models <- h2o.automl(
    x = predictors, 
    y = target,
    training_frame = train_conv_h2o,
    leaderboard_frame = valid_conv_h2o,
    max_runtime_secs = 3600,
    seed = 1234
)
```

When `max_runtime_secs` is set to `1800` there is no issue, but anything beyond this value will result in error below.

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 
  Unexpected CURL error: getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
```

I am on Ubuntu 20.04, R Version 3.6.3, h2o version 3.32.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to number of descriptors setting in linux. The `cron` environment is different than the system environment when running the script in interactive mode.

As a solution I have used extra parameter in my `cron` :

```
0 18 21 6 * ulimit -nS 1048576 && Rscript <script_name>
```

Then the error disappeared and the script ran correctly.